# How to temporarily remove one past changest from master branch and merge back in the future?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, revert

I am looking for the best way to temporarily remove one past changest(merged from feature branch) from the master branch which is already pushed to the server, considering that I don't want to lose those changes as in the future we shall merge them back to the master.

We are using GIT as a source control tool. Basically when we are working on a new functionality following the flow given below:

- Firstly, we create a new feature branch from the master branch.
- After finishing the coding on the feature branch(there can be multiple commits), do rebase onto master and create Pull Request(PR).
- After PR reviewed, changes are being merged to the master.

The below snapshot is from the master branch which is the result of this command:

`git log --graph --decorate --oneline`

```
*   e7655f500 Merged PR Z:
|\
| * bc255d318
| * 7d26a7a07
| * a6a46df89
|/
*   f1580b24b Merged PR Y:
|\
| * 9363bd302
| * b15ec84dc
| * a37209071
| * 5659763bd
|/
*   d9cc23826 Merged PR X:
```

I want to remove merges came with **SHA f1580b24b**, so, the master *logically* should become something like below(of course there can be more changeset regarding revert or other commands on top of **SHA e7655f500**):

```
*   e7655f500 Merged PR Z:
|\
| * bc255d318
| * 7d26a7a07
| * a6a46df89
|/
*   d9cc23826 Merged PR X
```

I also need to keep below changes somewhere(e.g. a new feature branch) so that in the future I can merge them back to master:

```
*   f1580b24b Merged PR Y:
|\
| * 9363bd302
| * b15ec84dc
| * a37209071
| * 5659763bd
|/
```

Some day in the future we decide to put back the changes we removed from the master branch (it is possible since that time new merges made to the master):

```
*   f1580b24b Merged PR Y:
|\
| * 9363bd302
| * b15ec84dc
| * a37209071
| * 5659763bd
|/
*   f8655f500 Merged PR A:
|\
| * cd255d318
| * 8e26a7a07
|/
*   e7655f500 Merged PR Z:
|\
| * bc255d318
| * 7d26a7a07
| * a6a46df89
|/
*   d9cc23826 Merged PR X
```

I might use **git revert** as an option and in the future **un-revert** it, but not sure about its impacts on the master branch mainline. Please advise what is the best approach to follow to achieve this?

Comment: I would recommend seeing what a `git revert` in a new branch comes up with.  Since git history "builds" on past diffs, you can't necessarily change history as easily as you can change the file contents.  `git revert` will do this.  That doesn't mean the code it ends up with will work in your codebase, though!

Comment: After removing that specific changeset might leave code not building state. But I am ok with that, failing parts can be fixed, as long as I can bring it back to the master branch in the future.